# Manifest Defined Broadcast Receiver for email CRUD

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Looking to define a Broadcast Receiver in the Manifest so I don't have to run as a service. My goal is to check any new email addresses that are created updated, deleted. Having issues, I have tried a few things. From another post I am trying this:

```
<receiver 
          android:name="EmailReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person"
                android:host="contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class EmailReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Did this work?");

    }
}
```

I have also tried the `<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2">` which also resulted in no changes when I edit a contact's email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to check any new email addresses that are created updated, deleted.

There are no broadcast `Intents` for those operations, AFAIK.

> From another post I am trying this :

`ACTION_EDIT` is an activity action. You can tell this because [the documentation says that `ACTION_EDIT` is an activity action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT). This is not used for broadcasts.

Comment: So best bet is to start a service as sticky, and just register a content observer. Wanted to avoid that, but guess that will work.

Comment: @Chrispix: IMHO, the best bet is to not do it at all. Why do you think that you need to be notified, in real time, continuously, when the user updates her contacts?

Comment: Ok maybe a better way to go about this is to ask this question. On the default Quick Contact Badge, I need to get an icon to show up (like skype does, for chat/voice/video), for any user who has email addresses. I have tried to add an intent filter for email_v2, but all it seems to do is puts a record under the email icon in a QCB. It looks like to be able to get an icon which appears also for accounts w/ Email addresses, I need to sync my own contacts and duplicate the email records w/ my own mimetype. Basically if a user has an email account, I want them to be able to initiate a meeting

Comment: via the email address listed in contacts. If you have a suggestion on how to accomplish this, it would be great.

Comment: @Chrispix: The QCB no longer exists as of Android 4.0.

Comment: Has it been replaced? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Chrispix: It's more that it doesn't show up in the contacts app on a Galaxy Nexus. On Android 2.x, a long press on the contact photo (or placeholder) brings up the QCB. On Android 4.0, a long press on the same thing brings up a dialog. It's possible that the ways you get into the QCB will get you into this dialog, but I would research that before you spend tons of time on the problem. To be honest, your approach has issues (everlasting service, getting out of sync if your service is not running, etc.), and I am really rather scared of it.

Comment: I need to go look at the ICS source then, tapping a photo in contacts on ICS (GalNex) or on the Contact Widget on the desktop both provide a 'dialog' widget which offers all the same functionality of the pre 4.0 widgets just in a different layout. From what I can tell, it is just a new layout, is it not?

Comment: As far as issues w/ the Service, do you see any other way. I am trying to accomplish this w/out changes to the framework, but need to hook into email addresses on the QCB (Or what ever it is now)

Comment: @Chrispix: "From what I can tell, it is just a new layout, is it not?" -- tough for me to say, as I'm not seeing any third party stuff show up. It may be I just don't have an app that would appear there installed and/or configured. "do you see any other way" -- I have never tried hooking into the QCB.

Comment: IF you download skype, it will hook in on ICS and show up to 3 icons per sync'd contact. It allows one to escalate to a call/video/chat from the new QCB (which is more like a huge dialog now). From what I can tell from our investigation it is available to 3rd parties using the Contacts QCB in your own app. Just trying to figure out the best way to hook into email addresses. Looks like creating mime type w/ custom data field in data table is the only way to go about getting our own icon on the QCB. As I mentioned I tried using the email_v2, but that shows up under the email tab, not its own tab